# Weblogic 12c Database Connection Error

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle12c, weblogic12c

I have just completed a fresh new installation of Oracle Fusion Middleware 12c. This one came with a new version of Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0. Whenever I try to create a new JDBC connection I receive the below error.

```
<BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish a connection because of java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ONS configuration failed
            at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.testConnection0(DataSourceUtil.java:423)
            at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.access$000(DataSourceUtil.java:24)
            at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil$1.run(DataSourceUtil.java:285)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.testConnection(DataSourceUtil.java:282)
            at com.bea.console.utils.jdbc.JDBCUtils.testConnection(JDBCUtils.java:937)
            at com.bea.console.actions.jdbc.datasources.creategridlinkdatasource.CreateGridLinkDataSource.testJDBCConnection(CreateGridLinkDataSource.java:615)
            at com.bea.console.actions.jdbc.datasources.creategridlinkdatasource.CreateGridLinkDataSource.testRACConnectionConfiguration(CreateGridLinkDataSource.java:437)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:870)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(FlowController.java:809)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.internalExecute(FlowController.java:478)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowController.internalExecute(PageFlowController.java:306)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java:336)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.FlowControllerAction.execute(FlowControllerAction.java:52)
            at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.access$201(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:97)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor$ActionRunner.execute(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2044)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:64)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.ActionInterceptor.wrapAction(ActionInterceptor.java:184)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.invoke(ActionInterceptors.java:50)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:58)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors.wrapAction(ActionInterceptors.java:87)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2116)
            at com.bea.console.internal.ConsolePageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(ConsolePageFlowRequestProcessor.java:265)
            at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processInternal(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:556)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.process(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:853)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.AutoRegisterActionServlet.process(AutoRegisterActionServlet.java:631)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowActionServlet.process(PageFlowActionServlet.java:158)
            at com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.process(ConsoleActionServlet.java:262)
            at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
            at com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.doGet(ConsoleActionServlet.java:134)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:1199)
            at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:1129)
            at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.framework.internal.PageFlowUtilsBeehiveDelegate.strutsLookupInternal(PageFlowUtilsBeehiveDelegate.java:43)
            at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.framework.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:108)
            at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.executeAction(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:707)
            at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.processActionInternal(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:141)
            at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.PageFlowStubImpl.processAction(PageFlowStubImpl.java:108)
            at com.bea.portlet.adapter.NetuiActionHandler.raiseScopedAction(NetuiActionHandler.java:111)
            at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:181)
            at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:167)
            at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.handlePostbackData(NetuiContent.java:225)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$2.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:180)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:324)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:130)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:399)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:352)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runInbound(Lifecycle.java:184)
            at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:159)
            at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:465)
            at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:291)
            at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:219)
            at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:275)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
            at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.service(MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.java:64)
            at weblogic.servlet.AsyncInitServlet.service(AsyncInitServlet.java:125)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
            at com.bea.console.internal.ParamFilter.doFilter(ParamFilter.java:38)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3701)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3667)
            at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
            at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
            at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
            at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1703)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1663)
            at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
            at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
            at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
            at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
            at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
            at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
```

I have banging my head into it for some time now and Google wasn't much help. Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have done some digging and found the solution. The cause of the problem was that for some reason the FAN service was implicitly enabled in the server configuration. I made it work by adding the below line to the **JAVA_OPTIONS** in ***setDomainEnv.sh*** file.

```
-Doracle.jdbc.fanEnabled=false
```

Now everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

As someone pointed out, we need to add `-Doracle.jdbc.fanEnabled=false` in setDomainEnv file (.sh for UNIX and .cmd for windows).

For windows, replace the last occurrence of `set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS%` with `set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Doracle.jdbc.fanEnabled=false` in setDomainEnv.cmd file located at the path "YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.3\DefaultDomain\bin

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that setting up the Oracle Notification Service (ONS) subscription(s) could not be set up.
If you specified the ONS configuration explicitly, then check that the syntax is correct.  It's documented at
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/JDBCA/gridlink_datasources.htm#JDBCA461
Alternatively, you can leave the ONS string blank and auto-ONS will take over.

Comment: I did not add any specific configuration to the ONS. Anyway, I have found the cause and solved the problem. I will add an answer below.